# Why is the textContent not being replaced but rather added to when function is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, frontend

```
const passwordBoxLeft = document.getElementById('password-box--left');
const passwordBoxRight = document.getElementById('password-box--right');

let passwordLeft = [];
let passwordRight = [];
let passwordLength = 15;

function generatePassword() {
  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
    let leftPW = characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)];
    let rightPW = characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)];
    passwordLeft.push(leftPW);
    passwordRight.push(rightPW);
  };

  passwordBoxLeft.textContent = passwordLeft.join('');
  passwordBoxRight.textContent = passwordRight.join('');
};
```

I have a simple frontend password generator that takes a `characters` array and generates 15 random characters from said array, pushes this into container arrays and these arrays are then displayed as `textContent` on the DOM.

Everything works well but for some reason, I am not understanding how to replace the `textContent` divs with a new rendition of a random password. Instead, the function is acting as if I have placed a `+=` for textContent so it keeps joining on another 15 random characters and so on everytime it is clicked, rather than showing just a new set of 15 random characters. This is obviously not the intended behaviour.

I can't seem to workout what I am doing wrong exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.push()` method which adds one or more elements to the end of `Array`. It will always return new length of the `Array`.

---

In your case - `.push()` is adding new generated array to previously modified array.

---

```js
let passwordLeft = [];
let passwordRight = [];
let passwordLength = 15;
let characters = `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`;
function generatePassword() {
  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
    let leftPW = characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)];
    let rightPW = characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)];
    passwordLeft[i] = leftPW;
    passwordRight[i] = rightPW;
  };
console.log(passwordLeft.join(""));
console.log(passwordRight.join(""));

}
generatePassword();
```

Comment: I completely missed the idea of this, thank you for your explanation!